# When one of the fetches fails, all of the fetches will not show

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am using the Flickr API to first fetch a gallery, and then fetch all the foto's in that gallery one by one.

However, when one of the photo's return a 404 the entire function will fail.

Is it possible to just skip that single instance?

Example code:

```
/**
 * @param {string} url The url to perform the fetch on
 */
async function getJSON(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * @param {string} urlGallery The URL to fetch the gallery from
 * @param {string} urlPhoto The URL to fetch the photo meta information from
 */
export default async function getGalleryPhotos(urlGallery, urlPhoto) {
  const galleryPhotoResponseJSON = await getJSON(urlGallery);

  const photos = galleryPhotoResponseJSON.photos.photo.map(async (photo) => {
    const { title } = photo;
    const photoUrl = `${urlPhoto}&photo_id=${photo.id}`;
    const photoResponseJSON = await getJSON(photoUrl);
    return { ...photoResponseJSON, title };
  });
  return Promise.all(photos);
}

const galleryDomNode = document.getElementById('js-gallery');
const loader = document.getElementById('js-loading');

getGalleryPhotos(apiUrlGallery, apiUrlPhoto)
  .then((data) => {
    generateCardHTML(data, galleryDomNode);
    galleryDomNode.removeChild(loader);
  })
  .catch((rej) => {
    const errorFeedback = document.createElement('section');
    galleryDomNode.removeChild(loader);
    errorFeedback.innerHTML = `
      <h2>An error occured.</h2>
      <p>${rej}</p>
    `;
    galleryDomNode.appendChild(errorFeedback);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation of `Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when
>   **all of the promises passed** as an iterable have resolved or when the
>   iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first
>   promise that rejects.The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise
>   that resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have
>   resolved or when the iterable contains no promises. **It rejects with
>   the reason of the first promise that rejects**.

To solve this, make sure each of your mapped promises resolves successfully. You can resolve with an error object instead of a real photo (or a constant '404 photo'), to make sure they all resolve successfully.

Comment: Isn't that already been taken care of in the `getJSON()` function? That will either return the response or an error. What is missing there?

Comment: When you return/throw an error, your promise rejects, and therefore `all` rejects. Instead, catch the error, but return (don't throw) something that signifies an error.